# Measuring the moderating effect in my analysis?

Tags: regression, spss, interaction

I'm trying to analyze if the volume and sentiment (valence) of tweets has an effect on the sales of a product (in my case movies). The DV is sales with IV NumberOfTweets, Valence, DaysSinceRelease.

My regression analysis showed that NumberOfTweets is highly significant for Sales (p = .000) while Valence wasn't (p = .731) and, kinda obvious, so was Days Since Release (p = .000).

I would now also like to analyze how Valence moderates it effects as my hypothesis states that higher valence leads to higher volume (in turn higher sales). How would ago about measuring this?

Answer (score 3):

Testing a moderation is just testing the interaction. So, multiply valence by tweets and add that to the model. You will probably want to center both variables first (by subtracting the mean).

By the way, you can't say "effect" in such an analysis. You can't say anything causal. I'd guess, in this case, that the causality goes both ways, and that there are many other causes, as well. And many of these other causes will affect BOTH number of tweets and sales (e.g., advertising budget, star quality of actors, number of theaters and who knows what else).